# Docker pull access denied for phpmyadmin image

Tags: docker, phpmyadmin, docker-compose

I want to pull [this phpmyadmin image](https://hub.docker.com/r/phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin/).
My docker-compose looks like this:

```
services:
   admin:
       image: phpmyadmin:phpmyadmin
       restart: always
       ports:
           - "8088:80"
       volumes:
           - /sessions
```

I am not sure about the *image* tag. I got the phpmyadmin:phpmyadmin from the [github page.](https://github.com/phpmyadmin/docker/blob/master/docker-compose.yml). But now when doing

```
docker login && docker-compose up
```

I get this error message:

```
ERROR: pull access denied for phpmyadmin, repository does not exist or may require 'docker login'
```

How can i login correctly? The image name is correct (i think) since i also tried with other version tags e.g. 4.7

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The tags are here:

https://hub.docker.com/r/phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin/tags/

the yaml should look like this:

```
services:
   admin:
       image: phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin:latest
       restart: always
       ports:
           - "8088:80"
       volumes:
           - /sessions
```

you could try the correct path and tag by first do a docker pull manually.

```
  docker pull phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin:<some-tag>
```

For example:

```
[root@host01 ~]# docker pull phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin:latest
Trying to pull repository registry.access.redhat.com/phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin ... 
Trying to pull repository docker.io/phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin ... 
latest: Pulling from docker.io/phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin
911c6d0c7995: Pull complete 
2527cc05836d: Pull complete 
3299172a2d6d: Pull complete 
05782106624f: Pull complete 
3e3261543ec8: Pull complete 
ce1c845d4246: Pull complete 
e005e70f55dc: Pull complete 
84403a106e16: Pull complete 
e4fc13f7949f: Pull complete 
2a53e72ea7b9: Pull complete 
d791f6b71f27: Pull complete 
576bdfd7cc75: Pull complete 
20768032f0fb: Pull complete 
fc8aa3d46064: Pull complete 
bade7addd704: Pull complete 
4b30a4dd0b24: Pull complete 
b02d6e91d2b5: Pull complete 
Digest: sha256:6fa491d4e3994ab3ec3410409bf0d59436072df1cfb16b8fe25c47486988103f
Status: Downloaded newer image for docker.io/phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin:latest
```

Comment: Perfect. That was what i needed